# Security Warning on Android 5 device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have used wifi permission on the Xamarin android application, it ask for Security Warning permission only on Android 5 device.

Note: There is no security warning on any other device.

[Developer settings image from the 5.1 device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqYAI.png)

[image: This is the page]

Comment: Like like an OEM specific warning, which OEM made that Lollipop device?

Comment: Definitely an OEM specific warning.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will check this issue by enabling the OEM settings from Developer Settings.

Comment: @SushiHangover, i have checked for the OEM options on the device which am testing. But it doesn't have that option. 

Device name : ulefone be touch 2 [Android 5.1]

Can you let me know what am missing here?

Comment: I have edited the post by adding the image of the Developer settings on that mobile. Also you can see the link from : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqYAI.png

Note: On other mobiles like htc, google nexus i can see the OEM settings.

Comment: @SelvaV I am not saying the you can turn that dialog off, I'm saying that the OEM of the device modified the base ASOP and added it as a "security feature".

Comment: @SushiHangover, Do we have any Event/method to override the Allow/Deny button from the Security Warning popup?